# Is there any difference on power charger between iPhone 6 vs 6s?

Tags: iphone, charger

Is there any difference on power charger between iPhone 6 vs 6s?

I'm worried that there is a difference and that I'll have issues when I use the iPhone 6 charger for iPhone 6s

It looks similar but can I get it confirmed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both use Lightning cable, so we are good there.
Regarding power, the 12W charger is compatible with all iPhones. See product [Compatibility](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD836LL/A/apple-12w-usb-power-adapter) section of 12W charger.

**iPhone Models**

```
iPhone  
iPhone 3G  
iPhone 3Gs  
iPhone 4  
iPhone 4s  
iPhone 5  
iPhone 5c  
iPhone 5s  
iPhone 6  
iPhone 6 Plus  
iPhone 6s  
iPhone 6s Plus
```

So you should be confident of charging iPhone 6 or 6s with up to 12W charger. The higher the wattage the lesser is the charging time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iPhone 6 charger for iPhone 6s and vice versa. You can even use your usb port on your Mac/PC to charge them both (however the charging might take a little more time than). There is no issue about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's safe to use iPhone 6 charger to iPhone 6s. As what the guys said, they have the same port and supports 12w charger so there should be no problem.